# How to write a Sql query for retrieving one row from duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have a User table which has many users but some users are  having same first name and Last Name but only one user will have status active . So my requirement is if the user is unique i need the user regardless of Status but if the user is duplicate  i need the record having status active.
How can i achieve this in SQL server?
Sorry For the confusion here is the example of User table

[image]

my result table should be

[image]

Here Steve Jordan is having 2 records so i need the record having status 1
and for records having distinct First name and last name i need all the records regard less of status.

Note : I have a user id as primary key but i am joining on first name and last name because other table doesn't have user id.

Comment: The DDL for this User table and the table being joined to it would be very helpful.

Comment: GROUP BY, MIN ( status).

Comment: Status is bit field,so unable to use min() function.

Comment: `status` and `user` column resides in same table ?

Comment: Your requirement is bit confusing.. Please share your table structure and an example of expected output. That will help us alot.

Comment: Are you just trying to get the data from the user table? Your question says you're joining to something.

Comment: Sorry i have corrected it.I need it on only user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT UserId, FirstName, LastName, Status FROM (
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName
                         ORDER BY Status DESC) AS rowNum
    FROM [User]
) u
WHERE u.rowNum = 1
```

This essentially groups by first and last name, orders by Status so that active are higher priority, and takes only one of each unique first/last name combination. This ensures that each each unique first/last name combination is in the result set only once, and if there are multiples, the active one is the one returned. If a name combination has multiples, but they are all not active, then only one is returned, chosen arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have the User ID PK in both tables, as this is much stronger relationally.

EDIT: A bit more complex, but this should give you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourOtherTable A
JOIN Users B
ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.FirstName = B.FirstName 
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM User GROUP BY FirstName, LastName HAVING COUNT(FirstName) = 1
) C
ON B.FirstName = C.FirstName AND B.LastName = C.LastName
WHERE B.Status = 1 OR C.FirstName IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: These queries don't seem to fulfill the OP's stated requirement "if the user is unique i need the user regardless of Status".

Comment: But for users that doesn't have duplicate first name and last name i need them regardless of status.Your query will be eliminating the inactive records for non duplicate first name and last name

Comment: Edited to include `STATUS BIT` and criteria for unique users.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you question. But, as per your subject line. It seems like you want the record, which is `active`, if record is duplicate.

```
select T.* from yourTable T INNER JOIN (select user, count(*) cnt FROM yourTable GROUP BY user) A ON A.user=T.user
WHERE A.cnt>1 and T.status='A';
```

If it wasn't your requirement. Then, I would ask you to share your table structure and expected output to understand better.